# как написать регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `str` и переменная `newStr`.
Как вывести из строки подстроку ограниченную c двух сторон `;`, содержащую эту переменную.

У меня пока получилось находить только переменную в строке.

```js
var regexp = new RegExp(newStr, 'ig');
var result = str.match(regexp);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Вы можете изменить значение в `newStr`? Или это значение приходит через API?

Comment: Если вы не можете изменить шаблон, придётся просто удалить эти точки с запятой, `console.log(result.replace(/^;|;$/g,''));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно динамически создать регулярное выражение, часть из которого содержится в переменной, можно так (в данном примере ограничители `;` не попадают в результат):

```js
const str = ';бла бла Луч бла бла;какой то текст ;бла бла опять Луч бла бла ;какой то текст;';
const newStr = 'Луч';
const regexp = new RegExp(`(?<=;)[^;]*${newStr}[^;]*(?=;)`, 'ig');
const result = str.match(regexp);
console.log(result);
```

```js
const str = ';бла бла Луч бла бла;какой то текст ;бла бла опять Луч бла бла ;какой то текст;';
const newStr = 'Луч';
const result = str.split(';').filter(substr => substr.includes(newStr));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Не работает.((
Выдает null.
Есть текст вида
 ;бла бла Луч бла бла;какой то текст ;бла бла опять Луч бла бла ;какой то текст;
Луч это значение переменной.Мне нужно вывести все строки с Луч.

Comment: То есть переменная содержит не всю подстроку между точками с запятой, а лишь часть этой подстроки?

Comment: Если да, то я отредактировал ответ согласно этому требованию.

Comment: И добавил ещё один вариант.

Comment: Спасибо большое.Все работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
\;.*;
```

Как вариант - дальше уберете 0 и последний символ из строки

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, нужно взять подстроку между двух `;`

> **regexp**: `(?<=;)[^;]+`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно посмотреть подробнее здесь - [демо](https://regex101.com/r/KTlkRz/3/)